# React router Link wrong url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router

I am using React router with Link to change urls and navigate trough app. In list of readings I navigate user to reading edit with this code:

```
 <Link to={`readings/edit/${reading.id}`} params={{id: reading.id}}>
```

I have defined the following routes:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Greetings}/>
        ...
        <Route path="readings/edit/:id" component={requireAuth(ReadingEdit)}/>
        <Route path="readings/:tab" component={requireAuth(ReadingListContainer)}/>
        ...
    </Route>
```

The navigation works as it should, but the URL is wrong it should be `http://localhost:8000/readings/edit/5` but instead it is `http://localhost:8000/readings/readings/edit/5`. This means that when I refresh site the router does not find a path.

How can I sole that problem?

Comment: Have you tried adding a / before readings in your Link tag?

Comment: ohh man, that is the solution. Big thanks, and I was speding like 2 hours to figure that one out... But why does Link do that???

Comment: Link probably uses / as the root path and adds the rest of it to the root. If you don't use / the it is using the current URL in your browser as root. So my guess is the URL you are routing from is "http://localhost:8000/readings/"

Comment: Also, please mark my answer as the current one. Otherwise your post will stay as unsolved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As discussed in the comment, adding a / before readings in your Link tag will fix the issue.